# perl module to split/mask intervals

Tags: perl, intervals

I am using the Set::IntervalTree code to compare two sets of intervals. However, I need an extra method that AFAIK is currently not implemented in this module.

I would like to have a method that splits or masks one interval into two or more. For example:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx    <= [Original Interval A]
           rrrrrrrrr                    <= [Interval B to mask against A]
xxxxxxxxxxx         xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx    <= [Resulting Intervals A1 and A2]
```

Any ideas if this is possible with an existing Perl module?

EDIT:

For more information, each interval can be of size 1 to 1 billion (1E9) and in each interval set there are between 1 to 1 million (1E6) intervals.

Comment: Your question seem unclear: Wĥat's an *interval*? Are you working on *strings*? Please add some explanations about your goals, some details, samples or already done scripts.

Comment: Have you seen `Set::IntSpan`, `Set::IntSpan::Fast`, and `Set::IntSpan::Fast::XS`? They have all the basic set operations: union, intersection, difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Set::IntSpan` does want you want, assuming you need integer boundaries for your intervals:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Set::IntSpan;

my $A    = new   Set::IntSpan '1-1000000000';
my $B    = new   Set::IntSpan '3-5,10-20,100-200,1000-2000';
my $C    = diff $A $B;

print $C;
```

returns

> 1-2,6-9,21-99,201-999,2001-1000000000

Comment: Cool thanks. What's the difference with Set::IntSpan, and the Fast and Fast::XS versions of it?

Comment: I haven't looked at Fast, but Fast::XS has a C module with it which you must compile to install. I presume it's much faster, if it turns out you need that.

Comment: Ok, I'll start with the default one, see what kind of performance I get, and try the other ones if it's too slow.

Comment: If you think this answers your question, can you accept the answer before the bounty expires?  If not, let me know what's missing.

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. I didn't know about the `diff $A $B` notation, I am more used to `$A->diff($B)`.